# Replacement for 5610 Transistor

Tags: transistors, repair, remote-control

I have a circuit (from a RC car) that uses a 5610 transistor, which can't find in store.

Is there any equivalent transistor?

Here are pictures of the board ([click here for high resolution images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI3Jc.jpg)):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Picture? Schematic?

Comment: Maybe it's a 2N5610?

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer, maybe a TPT5610?

Comment: We don't know what a "5610" transistor is.  At best that is a partial model number.  It could also be some in house part number.  A picture and schematic or full part number would help.  Without those, this question is too vague and needs to be closed.

Comment: Is "5610" the only markings you can make out?

Comment: does the circuit have identical transistors that you can measure some properties of?

Answer (score 1):

There is a silicon NPN transistor whose code is just 5610.
The only replacement part listed in *{dead link}* is NTE24.